# How to search a pivot table for rows that are owned by two users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to Laravel.

I have two models and a pivot table:

User

`id | name | password`

```php
public function conversations(): ?BelongsToMany
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Conversation

`id`

```php
public function users(): ?BelongsToMany
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

conversation_user

`id | conversation_id | user_id`

I create a conversation and assign the users with sync like so:

```php
$user->conversations()->syncWithoutDetaching($conversation);
$targetUser->conversations()->syncWithoutDetaching($conversation);
```

Users can have many conversations, and conversations can have multiple users. This is fine, but when I want to get a conversation with two specific users I don't know the best way to utilize the ORM to find the conversation they're both apart of.

I am currently using this next method, which works but it feels like there is a much better way of doing things utilizing the ORM:

```php
/**
 * Get a conversation by a target user id.
 *
 * @param int $targetUserId
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getConversationByTargetUserId(int $targetUserId)
{
    // Get the current user.
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();

    // Check the user exists.
    if (!$user) {
        throw new HttpException(500);
    }

    /**
     * Get all pivot tables where the
     * user ID is from the current user.
     */
    $userConversationIdsArray = DB::table('conversation_user')->where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('conversation_id');

    /**
     * Get all pivot tables where the user
     * id is equal to the target id, and is
     * also owned by the current user. Return
     * the first instance that we come across.
     */
    $targetConversation = DB::table('conversation_user')->where(['conversation_id' => $userConversationIdsArray, 'user_id' => $targetUserId])->first();

    /**
     * Return the conversation.
     */
    return Conversation::find($targetConversation->conversation_id);
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Not related to question, but what is this syntax? `?BelongsToMany { ... }`

Comment: @user8555937 This means the return value can be Null. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: It's called a return type declaration, it means that the function will return either null or a BelongsToMany, you can read about them here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fjarlaegur they put me on the right track. The following method works:

```php
/**
 * Get a conversation by a target user id.
 *
 * @param int $targetUserId
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getConversationByTargetUserId(int $targetUserId)
{
    // Get the current user.
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();

    // Check the user exists.
    if (!$user) {
        throw new HttpException(500);
    }

    return $user->conversations()->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($targetUserId) {
        $query->where('users.id', $targetUserId);
    })->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you are not utilising Eloquent? It might make it easier.

It could be done like this as you already have the user.

```
$user->conversations()->has('users.id', '=', $targetUserId)->first();
```

(I have not tested this solution so i am not sure this works 100%)

Also, there might be a typo in your first query. Might be a copy paste error might be a typo. Just making sure.

```
$userConversationIdsArray = DB::table('conversation_user')->where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id'); <---- 'id' shouldn't that be 'conversation_id'?
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes sorry that was a typo. I'll edit it now. I tried the code you provided, but got a stack error: ``Call to undefined method App\User::id()``

Comment: Ah i thought it could be done with properties too. But apparently `has()` works with relationships only. Glad you worked it out :) Do not forget to mark your question as answered!

Comment: Thank you :) It says I can answer my own question tomorrow.